# How to convert Date object without hours stamp to desired hours stamp

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to convert the "from" date object starting from 00:00:01 and "to" date object ending with 23:59:59. How do i do that. Here's my code.

```
let from = new Date(req.params.from);
let to = new Date(req.params.to);
console.log('from: ',from,'to: ',to)
```

result of console:

```
from:  2024-01-25T00:00:00.000Z to:  2024-01-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

I tried this method:

```
from.setHours(0,0,0,1);
to.setHours(23,59,59,999)
```

its result was:

```
2024-01-24T18:30:00.001Z 2024-01-25T18:29:59.999Z
```

Here hour stamp starts with 18 and ends in 06

Comment: Please post the actual input and the desired output. You likely want to look at toISOString

Comment: This may help https://jsfiddle.net/ja1tys6k/

Comment: What is `12,29` supposed to do? If you want 23.59 in the result?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake.. i was checking with several time zones to correct it.. its 23:59

Comment: The result is displayed as UTC, so I suppose you want UTC, so use *setUTCHours* and the hour and minute will be as you require. *setHours* sets the local hour, so you are seeing the UTC timestamp offset by your local offset (which seems to be +5:30).

Comment: BTW, you likely want to start at 00:00:00.000, otherwise you miss the first millisecond of the day. ;-)

Comment: If this is for a DB query and you are only interested in the *date*, then only compare dates, don't confuse the db query and yourself by adding times.   On the db query, remove the time part and compare the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.
I do not know if you are aware of how setHours works.

**Here is a simple description:**
When you create a Date object using a string like '2024-01-25T00:00:00.000Z', it is automatically interpreted as being in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). However, when you use the setHours method, it adjusts the time based on your local time zone.

**This is how you would achieve this.**

```js
let from = new Date('2024-01-25T00:00:00.000Z');
let to = new Date('2024-01-25T00:00:00.000Z');
from.setUTCHours(0, 0, 1, 0);
to.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
console.log(from.toISOString());
console.log(to.toISOString());
```

and the output is:

```
2024-01-25T00:00:01.000Z
2024-01-25T23:59:59.999Z
```

Comment: Thanks.. but i want the result in date datatype.. because iam perofrming an query operation in mongodb on a date field!

Comment: *i want the result in date datatype* - The `from`/`to` *are* date types.  Why do you think they are not?   The console.log is just providing a *representation* of that date, the code doesn't do `from = from.toISOString()` which would convert to a string.

Comment: So, will i get the datas between 00:00:01 and 23:59:59  if i perform with this result?

Comment: After running this code, from will be set to '2024-01-25T00:00:01.000Z' and to will be set to '2024-01-25T23:59:59.999Z'.

Assuming you use these from and to values in a MongoDB query to retrieve documents with a date field falling within this range, you should get documents with dates between 00:00:01 and 23:59:59 on January 25, 2024, in UTC.

Comment: @AhammedZulaikh—there is no "Date data type" in ECMAScript (there is only [these](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-ecmascript-language-types), undefined, null, boolean, string, symbol, numeric:number, numeric:BigInt and object). There are *Date* objects that are created by the *Date* constructor (aka *Date* instances).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this code:

```
  let from = new Date();
  let to = new Date();
  console.log('from: ',from,'to: ',to);
  from.setHours(0,0,1,0);
  to.setHours(23,59,59,999);
  console.log('from: ',from,'to: ',to);
```

and i got this output

```
from:  2024-01-25T10:47:36.870Z to:  2024-01-25T10:47:36.870Z
from:  2024-01-25T00:00:01.000Z to:  2024-01-25T23:59:59.999Z
```

Which looks to me like what you expected.

Comment: from:  2024-01-24T18:30:00.001Z to:  2024-01-25T18:29:59.999Z
what iam getting is this. I think its because its following UTC. iam getting correct output if i set it with 5:30:01 which is the time difference btw our local time and UTC

Comment: Actually when I ran it on my pc i got a different result based on my time zone.
The output I got here is from my EC2 server which is in UTC time zone